# Cocoa topmost window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

How could I get one of my Cocoa application windows to get (and maintain) on top all desktop windows while my apllication stay running?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Re-order a window to be on top of all others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550138/how-do-you-re-order-a-window-to-be-on-top-of-all-others-in-cocoa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at NSWindow's -setLevel: method:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setLevel:

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the window key and order it to front. Use this

```
[[myWindowController window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

Comment: LooPer wants the window to *stay* in front of *all* desktop windows, not just bring it in front of other windows in the same app.